# Internal Server Error when attempting to connect to Kubernetes dashboard -- TLS issues

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, traefik

I'm trying to expose an ingress port to the kubernetes dashboard running in https via Traefik, but not having much luck. I'm using k3s.

Using cert-manager I've obtained certificates for the dashboard domain and reflected these into the kubernetes-dashboard namespace. I have then configured kubernetes-dashboard to use these following this guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/installation.md#recommended-setup

Then I defined an ingress route for the dashboard:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.serversscheme: https
spec:
  rules:
    - host: k8s.domain.co.uk
      http:  
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 443
  tls:
    - secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
      hosts:
        - k8s.domain.co.uk
```

This matches, but I get a 500 internal server error navigating to it, with the kubernetes dashboard logs saying

`2023/03/05 14:09:22 http: TLS handshake error from 10.42.0.8:58448: remote error: tls: bad certificate`

In the traefik logs I see `level=debug msg="'500 Internal Server Error' caused by: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.42.0.3 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"`

So I assume there's something wrong with the certs the dashboard is using. They are Let's Encrypt certificates for the domain k8s.mydomain.co.uk. Do they need to be for some other domain?

I have reviewed the following questions:

- https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/ssl-issue-while-reaching-kubernetes-dashboard seems promising but if I use the `IngressRoute` over `Ingress` I get a 404, with nothing in the Traefik logs
- [Kubernetes Dashboard TLS cert issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820535/kubernetes-dashboard-tls-cert-issue) seems to be my exact issue

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For now I was able to work around the issue by adding the following to `var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/manifests/traefik-config.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChartConfig
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  valuesContent: |-
    globalArguments:
      - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
```

as described in https://docs.k3s.io/helm#customizing-packaged-components-with-helmchartconfig